# select_related between three or more models

Tags: python, django

When using select_related in Django, you can get from A to B
to a foreign key, you would write the following

```
A.objects.select_related('B')...
```

What should I write if I am referencing a foreign key from B to C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `select_related` to follow a foreign key relationship from A to C *via* B, you can chain the related field using double underscores, like this:

```
A.objects.select_related('B__C')
```

This will fetch the related B and C objects using an SQL join, which can help you avoid additional database queries when accessing the related objects later in your code.